# Hazelcast Serialization Exception when trying to deserialize date object

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, hazelcast

I am having nested class which is having date field along with other primitive fields. I have implemented DataSerializable interface of both Outer and Inner classes.

Outer class

```
public class Outer implements DataSerializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Long number;

private String enumerationType;

private Basic basic;
.
.
.

@Override
public void readData(ObjectDataInput in) throws IOException {
    number = in.readLong();
    enumerationType = in.readUTF();
    basic = new Basic();
    basic.readData(in);
}

@Override
public void writeData(ObjectDataOutput out) throws IOException {
    out.writeLong(number);
    out.writeUTF(enumerationType);
    basic.writeData(out);
}

}
```

Inner class - Basic

```
private class Basic implements DataSerializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
    private String d;
    private String e;
    private String f;
    private String g;
    private String h;
    private String i;

    private Date date1;
    private Long long1;

    private Date date2;
    private Long long2;

@Override
    public void readData(ObjectDataInput in) throws IOException {

        Field[] fields = HazelcastUtil.ReflectUtil.getFields(this.getClass());
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (!java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())) {
                try {
                    if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(String.class)) {
                            field.set(this, in.readUTF());
                        } else if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(Long.class)) {
                            field.set(this, in.readLong());
                        }  else if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(Character.class)) {
                            field.set(this, in.readChar());
                        } else if (!field.getType().isAssignableFrom(Outer.class)) {
                            field.set(this, in.readObject(field.getType()));
                        }
                    //}
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void writeData(ObjectDataOutput out) throws IOException {
        //out.writeUTF(replacementNpi);
        Field[] fields = HazelcastUtil.ReflectUtil.getFields(this.getClass());
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (!java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())) {
                try {
                    Object value = field.get(this);
                    if (value != null) {
                        //HazelCastLogger.info(value.getClass()+" >> "+value.toString()+" >> "+field.getName() + " >> "+field.getType(),  this.getClass());
                        if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(String.class)) {
                            out.writeUTF((String) value);
                        } else if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(Long.class)) {
                            out.writeLong((Long) value);
                        }  else if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(Character.class)) {
                            out.writeChar((Character) value);
                        } else if (!field.getType().isAssignableFrom(Outer.class)) {
                            out.writeObject(value);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

While loading the map, I am facing below exception.

```
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: StreamSerializerAdapter{serializer=com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$DateSerializer@f8b802f} is not implementing the interface com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.TypedStreamDeserializer interface. Please implement this interface to deserialize for class class java.util.Date
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:55)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.readObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:294)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:580)
at com.entity.Outer$Basic.readData(Outer.java:626)
at com.entity.Outer.readData(Outer.java:155)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.readInternal(DataSerializableSerializer.java:158)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:105)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:50)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:48)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:191)
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.record.ObjectRecordFactory.newRecord(ObjectRecordFactory.java:37)
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.AbstractRecordStore.createRecord(AbstractRecordStore.java:95)
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.createRecord(DefaultRecordStore.java:78)
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.putFromLoadInternal(DefaultRecordStore.java:956)
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.putFromLoad(DefaultRecordStore.java:931)
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.PutFromLoadAllOperation.run(PutFromLoadAllOperation.java:74)
at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.call(Operation.java:148)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.call(OperationRunnerImpl.java:202)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:191)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:120)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:100)
```

The exception is specifically for the java.util.Date object.

> com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: StreamSerializerAdapter{serializer=com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$DateSerializer@f8b802f} is not implementing the interface com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.TypedStreamDeserializer interface. Please implement this interface to deserialize for class class java.util.Date

Could you please help me resolve the issue? I am using hazelcast IMDG version 3.10 along with maven and spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

Should

```
if (!field.getType().isAssignableFrom(Outer.class))
```

be

```
if (!field.getType().isAssignableFrom(Date.class))
```

The inner class doesn't have the outer class as a field, so won't need to serialize it. But it does have date fields and doesn't have the logic for this.

Also, if you're using reflection it's going to be slow

Comment: I have the if check to avoid serialization of outer class object field which is available as a field in Inner class as this$0, which causes a cyclic recursion. For all other objects, I need to serialize `if (!field.getType().isAssignableFrom(Outer.class))` Please check the negation condition used.

Comment: Try this then, add `} else if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(Date.class)) {
                            field.set(this, in.readObject());` and `} else if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(Date.class)) {
                            out.writeObject(value);` to your Basic class. Works for me! Needs to go before the line for Outer.class